# Finding the residue of function with Laurent series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n(A+By+Cy^{-1})^k}{\beta (\beta i)^n \ k!}$

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis

I have been trying to find the residue of $f(\omega) = \frac{e^{i \omega a} e^{\frac{-b  \omega}{\omega + ib}}}{i \omega}$ at the essential singularity $\omega = -ib$ for a while, but it is giving me a headache and I would really appreciate some help. For inspiration I have been looking at [Residue of $z^2 e^{1/\sin z}$ at $z=\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120282/residue-of-z2-e1-sin-z-at-z-pi/120450#120450)
and
[How to compute the residue of a complex function with essential singularity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50343/how-to-compute-the-residue-of-a-complex-function-with-essential-singularity)

This is my aproach so far: I moved the singularity to 0 by substituting $y = \omega + \beta i$, then I  rewrote and simplified the exponent to $A + By +Cy^{-1}$ which gives us the expression: $$\frac{-i}{y-\beta i}e^{A + By + Cy^{-1}}$$
where we want the residue at $y=0$
Then I used that 
$$\frac{-i}{y-\beta i} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n}{(\beta i)^n\beta }$$ 
for $|y|<|\beta|$ and wrote the exponential as an infinite sum to get:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n(A+By+Cy{^-1})^k}{\beta (\beta i)^n \ k!}$$

Now unless I'm mistaken, this should be the Laurent series of $f$, and we should be able to find the residue from this. I just can't wrap my head around the double sum and the triple binomial formula.

I would be very grateful for hints on how to proceed, or on a better approach if there is one.

Comment: Isn't it enough to find the limit as $\omega \rightarrow - b i$ of $(\omega + b i) f(\omega)$?

Comment: You can get $y^{-1}$ members exactly if $k=n+1$, and only from the $C$ part..

Comment: @vonbrand: in this case I'm afraid no, because it is *not a simple pole*.

Comment: @Berci I agree that we will have $y^{-1}$ when $k = n+1$ from the $C$ part, but we will have a whole lot more from combinations of $A,B$ and $C$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Ah yes, indeed.

Comment: Pull out factors that don't misbehave at the singularity, and work with the rest. That should get rid of much of the cruft that bothers you.

Comment: @vonbrand I think I did what you recommended, here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304025/does-sum-k-0-infty-sum-n-0-infty-fracbk-cnk1ibn

That sum is the residue (or almost, pulled out some factors)unless I'm mistaken. Just cant compute it :( hehe

Answer (score 1):

The expression can also be written as follows: $$ \frac{e^A}{\beta}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n y^k B^k y^{-j}C^{j}}{(i\beta)^n k! j!}$$
To find the residue we need the coefficient of $y^-1$, that is we need $ j = n+k+1$. Thus we need to solve $$\frac{e^A}{\beta}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{B^k C^{(n+k+1)}}{(i\beta)^n k! (n+k+1)!}$$ The sum here is solved in [Does $ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{B^k C^{(n+k+1)}}{(ib)^n k! (n+k+1)!}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304025/does-sum-k-0-infty-sum-n-0-infty-fracbk-cnk1ibn)
So finally the answer is  $\frac{e^{A+B}}{\beta}\left(\frac{e^C-e^{\frac{-iC}{\beta}}}{1+\frac{i}{\beta}} \right)$